# Is there a way to keep visual studio 2010 from switching threads when debugging?

Tags: multithreading, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I'm an old C++ guy who's been doing java for the past few years, but now I have to find a memory leak in a C++ program that nobody else can find. So I'm using VS2010 for the first time and when there's multiple threads going and I trace over a line in one thread that makes some system calls, it will change context to another thread.
Now I realize that's because that's what's actually going on, but in eclipse in java for example it won't switch threads on you unless you specifically pick another thread.
Is there a way to set a switch to do that in visual studio?

Comment: I found flagging a thread doesn't achieve this effect.

Comment: Fixed in service pack 1.

Comment: lucky for me then my company doesn't allow me to do updates. Oh well. Thanks.

Comment: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/